# AudioQueue Buffer is Empty in Callback

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-audio, audio-streaming, audioqueue

I am using AudioQueue to read the AudioBuffer which indirectly read the Audio input from Mic, 
But it seems, Callback is not hitting,

Below is logic in brief

1-- Run a Audio Thread

2 -- Create AudioQueue

3 -- Configure AudioQueue,

4 -- Process the Callback

5 -- When user wanted to stop the Audio flow,

6 -- Stop the AudioQueue

7 -- Stop the thread

Will provide you the code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, it seems, if you create the AudioQueue in "C" thread, it might not invoke the callback, and might be thats the issue,